# Can't execute jar from directory with umlaut

Tags: luatex, input-encodings, latexmk, shell-escape, lua

Okay so this is quite an exotic question and I am unsure whether it really fits on this page. But as it involves LaTeX I'll post it here.

I have written a Java program that I am calling from inside LaTeX via `\immedeiate\write18{java -jar <myJar>}`. This works great except for this edge case:

1. I am in a directory that contains an umlaut in it's name (e.g. `ä`)
2. I am using `lualatex` to compile the document
3. (I am using Linux) My System is KDE Neon 5.16 with a 4.18 kernel. I am using TexLive 2018 and my lualatex version is 1.07.0

If all of these conditions are met the call fails with the message `Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class <name> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null`.

I double-checked that I can call the jar from that directory via terminal and the call works when using e.g. `pdflatex` to compile the document (as soon as the umlaut is removed it also works with `lualatex`).

I also verified that I can write a lua script that calls the jar via `os.execute(...)` which is what lualatex uses via it's `shellesc` package to execute `\write18` commands. However as soon as I do the same command from inside LaTeX (via `\directlua`) I get the error message stated above.
I also checked with `print(_VERSION)` that lualatex uses the same lua version I tested my external script in.

Does anybody know what the problem here might be? Are there some further things lualatex does to its lua-environment that could be the problem?
Any thought on this is welcome.

EDIT: A friend of mine does not have this issue on a windows machine (though I am not a hundred percent sure he is actually using lualatex as well)

EDIT2:
Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    Some content so TeX won't complain
    \directlua{os.execute("java -jar <PathToArbitraryJarFile>")}
\end{document}
```

Put above code in a folder called `Testär` (or something else with an umlaut) and compile the document with `lualatex`

EDIT 3:
I tested it on my new machine and at least now I can only reproduce the error when using latexmk with the `-pdflatex=lualatex` option.

This problem only and exclusively comes up in the case of a directory with an umlaut in its name (never checked other special characters tbh) ...

Comment: Could you please show a MWE to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @TeXnician done

Comment: Apparently this occurs only if using `latexmk` though...